# SQLite Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OR'

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am trying to Insert or Replace into an SQLite DB using the following Query:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO VersionNumbers
(VersionNumberID,
ENVID,
EnvShortName,
VersionNumber,
BuildNumber,
SourceGetVersion,
DeploymentDate,
CreatedDateTime,
ModifiedDateTime,
Deleted,
LastGetFromServerDateTime)
Values
('da8e3589-4511-4300-a081-ff57998be949',
'd2303c80-ce8e-4a66-98ca-009b5073e967',
'Environment A',
'16.3.1610.2708', 
'BuildNumber_20161027.2', 
'C99633', 
'2016-10-31', 
'10/10/2016 12:35:41', 
'14/11/2016 10:55:15', 
'0',
'14/11/2016 15:21:05')
```

I have tested this using DB Browser for SQLite and executing the SQL directly on the database and that's all fine, but if i pass in the same query via C# I get the error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OR'."

C#

```
dbConnection.ConnectionString = DataDbConnString;
dbConnection.Open();
foreach (DataRow dataRow in dataTableVersion.Rows)
{
    try
    {
        var QueryUpdateOrInsert = @"INSERT OR REPLACE INTO VersionNumbers
                                      (VersionNumberID,
                                      ENVID,
                                      EnvShortName,
                                      VersionNumber,
                                      BuildNumber,
                                      SourceGetVersion,
                                      DeploymentDate,
                                      CreatedDateTime,
                                      ModifiedDateTime,
                                      Deleted,
                                      LastGetFromServerDateTime) Values (" +
                                      "'" + dataRow["VersionNumberID"] + "'," +
                                      "'" + dataRow["ENVID"] + "'," +
                                      "'" + dataRow["ENVShortName"] + "'," +
                                      "'" + dataRow["CurrentVersionNumber"] + "', " +
                                      "'" + dataRow["CurrentBuildName"] + "', " +
                                      "'" + dataRow["CurrentLastAssociatedChangeset"] +
                                      "'" + dataRow["DeploymentDate"] + "', " +
                                      "'" + dataRow["CreatedDateTime"] + "', " +
                                      "'" + dataRow["ModifiedDateTime"] + "', " +
                                      "'" + dataRow["Deleted"] + "', " +
                                      " '" + currentDateTimeUtc + "')";
        var sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(QueryUpdateOrInsert, dbConnection);
        var sda = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcmd);
        var sqlexe = sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Exception.Message);
    }
}
dbConnection.Close();
```

Comment: I had never seen `INSERT OR REPLACE`. I'd try to just use `REPLACE`, as this command would insert the row if it's not present.

Comment: Did you try using only REPLACE INTO instead of INSERT OR REPLACE INTO?

Comment: @Pikoh , i have just tried using REPLACE and it now error's with the following "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INTO'."

Comment: Is the database SQLite?

Comment: @Pikoh yes its a .db created by SQLite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are not using the `SQLite` commands/data adapters, but the ones designed for SQL Server. You need to install the [System.Data.SQLite .net Adapter](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki) and use the proper Sqlite conection,command, and adapters: `SQLiteConnection`,`SQLiteCommand` and `SQLiteDataAdapter`